# USSD Not Display Nokia Lumia 710 (Windows 7.8)

Tags: windows-phone-7, nokia

I am not able to use USSD string on my Nokia Lumia 710.
After using *121# (Airtel-India) number is dialling but response screen is not displayed.

I raise the query to concern operator in revert they told me to install SMS 2.0 on my Nokia Lumia 710 handset.

I am not able to find suggested software in windows phone market.

Can you please help me in that or give alternative to use USSD string on m Nokia Lumia 710 handset.